# How to draw outlined text efficiently?

Tags: wpf, drawing, formatted-text

At present, I'm using FormattedText.BuildGeometry() to get the geometry of text.

First, I draw the text geometry with a thicker pen, then on top of that I draw the text. The final effect is that the text seems to have an outline.

My problem is that the BuildGeometry() method is very time consuming. Is there any other way to draw text outlines efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago when I was working on J2ME, I use this method to make text have some outline (pseudocode, but it can be easily updated to WPF):

```
setColor(outlineColor)
drawText(x - 1, y, text)
drawText(x + 1, y, text)
drawText(x, y - 1, text)
drawText(x, y + 1, text)

setColor(textColor)
drawText(x, y, text)
```

(assuming you want to draw text at x, y coordinates).

I think drawing the text 4 times more might be faster than with BuildGeometry.

Comment: Outline can be of variable width; nice idea though. Anything else you wanna suggest?

Comment: The only other option I can think for the moment is to write your own Effect that achieves this, but this won't be trivial or at least try one of the .Net's effects http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.aspx (which are not Obsolete). If you are familiar with HLSL (or lucky with google) you can use PixelShader with a custom HLSL program. Sorry i cannot help more than this.